# How to integrate Angular 8 project in ASP.NET MVC using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: angularjs, angular, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I created an Angular 8 project using CLI and now I want to use this project in ASP.NET MVC using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: See https://dotnetdetail.net/how-to-create-an-angular-8-and-asp-net-core-3-app-using-vs2019/

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question as you asked it: To integrate an Angular 8 app into an ASP.NET MVC project, you'll have to use the CLI to generate the app in a folder inside of the MVC project. You would then need to set up routing in such a way that Angular knows when you are requesting an Angular component vs when you are requesting an MVC view. You would also need to remember to compile your Angular app before deploying. And don't deploy your Angular source files.

That being said, the better approach would be to use the Visual Studio Angular app with .Net Core Web Api project template which does much of the boring work for you. While it is technically possible to integrate Angular into an MVC application, it's probably a better idea to not mix the two and rather use a Web API backend and do ALL of the front end stuff in Angular. I do however understand that it's not always that simple, especially when working with existing systems which need to be migrated bit-by-bit.

Comment: But i wanted to login from MVC application and redirect to Angular app